# How do I make the padding all the same?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage

```
    <div class="col1"> SomeTextA </div> <div class="col2"> one </div>
    <div class="col1">TextB </div><div class="col2">  two </div>
.... some html....
    <div class="col1">SomeC </div><div class="col2">  three </div>
    <div class="col1">SomeD </div><div class="col2"> four </div>
```

I want the CSS to display a space in between so it all looked like aligned to each other.
It look like a table but it isnt a table.

```
SomeTextA                 one
TextB                     two
SomeC                     three
SomeD                     four
```

I tried with padding but it shifted left depends on the word length. Do i need to calculate each position and shift it one by one?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: @Quentin grid doesnt change. it still display the same.

Comment: Are you able to wrap those divs in a container/ wrapper?

Comment: will the in between there are some other html tags get effected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css grid layout to create two columns in this way:

```
container: {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

and then wrap your `div`s in a `div` with class `container`:

```
<div class="container">
 --> your code here
</div>
```